# AutoMapper instantiate complex types with StructureMap

Tags: .net, structuremap, automapper

Assuming that I have a complex type, for example:

```
interface IFoo
{
  IBar {get;set;}
}
```

and it is mapped to some DTO using AutoMapper, i.e. `Mapper.CreateMap<IFoo, FooDto>()`

How should I configure AutoMapper so that it will use StructureMap to get an instance of IFoo as well as IBar when mapping from FooDto to IFoo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Mapper.CreateMap<FooDto, IFoo>()
    .ConstructUsing(fooDto => ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IFoo>())
    .AfterMap((fooDto, iFoo) => iFoo.IBar = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IBar>());
```

Is IBar a dependency in the constructor of IFoo?  Then you could skip the `AfterMap()` step.